# Priority-web-sdk : How long can a form stay open after I started it? Is there a timeout?

Tags: javascript, erp

I want to know how long can a form stay active after I started it. Is there a timeout or a way to know the form is no longer active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server deactivates form sessions after extended periods of inactivity.

The SDK includes the [isAlive()](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#isAlive) function for determining if a form is still active.